# My overlay application starts without the background being clickable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, overlay

I am working on developing an overlay application for Android using Kotlin, but I'm encountering challenges with the overlay component. I initiate the overlay through a service, and while it does start, the background remains non-clickable. My goal is to make the background clickable. Whenever I press the back or home button it does function as an overlay.

```
private fun showOverlay() {
        val metrics = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics
        val width = metrics.widthPixels
        val height = metrics.heightPixels
        val layoutFlag: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        }
        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                (width * 0.4f).toInt(),
                (height * 0.15f).toInt(),
                layoutFlag,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
        params.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.BOTTOM
        val composeView = ComposeView(this)
        composeView.setContent {
            FloatingBottomContainer(homeScreenViewModel)
        }


        // This part is to trick the system by thinking it has a lifecycle.
        // This is needed to make the composable of JetPack compose work

        val viewModelStoreOwner = object : ViewModelStoreOwner {
            override val viewModelStore: ViewModelStore
                get() = ViewModelStore()
        }
        val lifecycleOwner = MockLifecycleOwner()
        lifecycleOwner.performRestore(null)
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        composeView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
        composeView.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(viewModelStoreOwner)
        composeView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(lifecycleOwner)

        // This is required or otherwise the UI will not recompose
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)


        windowManager.addView(composeView, params)
    }
```

I also request permissions for the overlay service, and I have tested this, confirming that it functions correctly. I look forward to your comments! Thank you!

Comment: Can you try using "FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE" instead of "FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE" in LayoutParams settings?

Comment: I just tried that, but unfortunately, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try using "FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH" in `WindowsManager.LayoutParams`

Comment: That also doesn't change anything unfortunately